# Cannot attach file to email in elementary os 5.0 juno

Tags: release-juno, ubuntu

I recently upgarded to elementary os juno. I had a few bugs that i sorted out but one that I can't figure out is trying to attach a file in email. When i click the "attach file" icon, the files window pops up and i can select a file but cannot attach it. The window doesn't have a button to allow me to add the file. It also doesn't have the close, minimize, and maximize icons. I have to press "esc" to close it. Anyone experiencing the same could maybe help me out here.Thanks.

Comment: For me the file chooser has the button to attach in the lower right corner. I could also succesfully attach a file by double-clicking on the file. Do you have any themes enabled? Do you use gnome-tweaks by any chance? Could you provide a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Hey Michael, double-clicking doesn't work for me. Yes I use gnome-tweaks and I'm using the "elementary" theme for Applications and Cursor and "Numix-Circle" for the icons. I can't seem to find a way to attach the screenshot.